# Where to post my question

Tags: discussion

I have a question about trying to find a very simple one page template for software development project request. The only ones i have found are very long and very specific. Where i work we get requests in the worst possible ways and often very vague. i would like to start trying to use some kind of small simple template for requests but no clue where to find one or where to even really ask this question. I am not even sure if this is the right place to ask this question about where to ask my other question lol.

Comment: It's worth mentioning there is a software recommendations site, but I don't know what their rules are on posting recommendation questions. If you take a look at it, be sure to read their [on-topic page first!](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Try a search engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not even sure if this is the right place to ask this question about where to ask my other question lol.

The best place to ask where a question belongs, before actually asking the question, is on the more general meta site, aka [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), using the `site-recommendation` tag. See: [Where do I ask where to ask?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168103/254929)

However, it's fine (even encouraged) to ask on a particular meta site whether a question would be appropriate for the corresponding main site, when you're not sure beforehand and there's no past discussion that applies. In this case, I'm in agreement with @SLawson that the type of request you're describing is not within the scope of Stack Overflow and your question would probably be closed right away.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure where the right place to ask this question is, but it's not Stack Overflow. Asking for a template would likely get closed quickly for requesting third-party resources.

That being said, if you take some time to try to write your own template and have issues with it, you can certainly come back to SO if you have a problem and can post a specific, answerable question about your issue. The same goes for modifying one of the "very long and very specific" templates you *can* find. Try to generalize it to suit your need, and come ask a good and specific question if you have issues.